# How to make a tooltip stay visible on mousenter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, tooltip

I have some toy code for a tooltip. It works okay, except that when you mouse into the tooltip it gets hidden with this logic.

I'm banging my head trying to figure out a clean way to get the tooltip to stay visible when you mouse into it, and disappear when you mouse out of both areas. Anyone have a suggestion?

[See the example.](http://jsfiddle.net/gNZfG/10/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var div1 = $("#div1");
var div2 = $("#div2").hide();

var hoverTimer;
div1.mouseenter(function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    div1.mousemove(function(e) {
        x = e.pageX;
        y = e.pageY;
    });
    hoverTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
        div2.css("left", x);
        div2.css("top", y);
        div2.show();
    }, 400);
});

div1.mouseleave(function(e) {
    window.clearTimeout(hoverTimer);
    div2.hide();
});
```

**CSS**

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
}
#div1 {
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
}
#div2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create the `mousemove` event, but aside from setting two variables you never actually move the tooltip. Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gNZfG/12/) instead. Note I added a 16-pixel "margin" on the mouse position - this is to make it more inline with actual tooltips, and prevents the flickering effect.

Comment: Oh cool, thanks. But this behavior is different than what I wanted. I don't actually want the tooltip to move with the mouse, I just want to be able to mouse into it while stationary without disappearing.

Comment: fyi I update the x/y with mousemove because it's on a timer and otherwise will appear where you *entered* the blue area

Comment: @TonyR: Movement is going to be the easiest way to solve this.  Otherwise, the tooltip hides the content, the user has no way of moving it out of the way, and it's just no fun.

Comment: In that case, you need [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gNZfG/13/). Removed the `mousemove` event since it's now unneeded. The important thing is that the tooltip element is now appended to the element the mouse is entering. That way, moving the mouse to the tooltip element won't count as a mouseleave.

Comment: I'm planning on having rich tooltips. The user will want to copy/paste text out of them.

Comment: You can keep the `mousemove`, although I suggest you detach the event when the timeout fires. The important thing is that `append()`.

Comment: @Kolink The mousemove is still necessary! With your code, the tooltip always shows up on the edge of the element, where your mouse *entered* the green area. I don't like that! Anyway your append idea looks to have done it. Thanks!

Comment: Plesae see the last comment I just posted.

Answer (score 0):

Best way for  showing tooltip  is using css only.

e.g

suppose I have element to which i have to give tooltip . i will give data attribute to that element and then with css i will access that attribute and then will show tooltip like below

```
<a data-tool-tip="my tool tip"> my link goes here</a> this is other text
```

and css will be like below

```
a[data-tool-tip]{
   position:relative;
}


a[data-tool-tip]::after {
    content: attr(data-tool-tip);
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    background:gray;
    padding:10px;
    color:white
    border-radius:5px
    font-size:0.8em;
    bottom:100%;
    left:0;
     white-space:nowrap; 
     transform:scale(0);
transition:transform ease-out 150ms;
    }

 a[data-tool-tip]:hover::after {
 transform:scale(1);
}
```

As tool-tip prepended to element itself using `::before`  selector it will be visible after mouse enter also;

**output will be like below**

[image]